# Running Long Process: Indexing 5GB docs with Lucene

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, lucene

Situation:I have an ASP .NET application that will search through docs using Lucene. I want to run the initial indexing (the index will be incremental after the initial run so there wont be need to index the whole directory again in future). Currently, I have about 5GB of docs (45000files).

Problem: My application times out before completing the process. I have altered the TimeOut like this:

HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 200000;

but it still does not complete the process.

How can I run the index?

Comment: What kind of timeout error does it give?

Comment: I ask because usually when I'm trying to prevent a timeout, there are frequently a number of ways to timeout and you need to prevent them all.  Ben has a valid point, however.  If you don't have to do it in a web page, don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't run these from ASP.NET.  Create a service that does the work for you, and kick it off via MSMQ, a "work_queue" table in the database, or whatever makes sense in your scenario.

Web Requests are intended to perform work quickly and immediately return, rather than do batch processing.

Comment: +1 for Ben's suggestion. Also suggest looking into Solr, it can take care of several issues for you. You can query Solr from ASP.NET using SolrNet.

Comment: @Mikos - On one of the projects, I could not use Solr because the site was hosted elsewhere. But, I have now used Nutch, Solr and SolrNet in my latest project and it works a treat. The documentation is not the best but the results are exactly what i was looking for.